# How to access a specific UIGestureRecognizer using MKMapView.gestureRecognizers

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, uigesturerecognizer

I add a UILongPressGestureRecognizer in my viewDidLoad method:

```
var uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: sMapView, action: "longPressDetected:")
    uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1
    sMapView.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)
```

and I am trying to disable it in my handler. This is my only gesture recognizer, and right now I am trying:

```
            var recognizerList = sMapView.gestureRecognizers
            var recognizer = uilpgrList[0] as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
            recognizer.enabled = false
```

I am getting an error: "cannot subscript a value of [AnyObject]? with an index of type 'Int'"

Comment: i know in obj c , do you want to know in Obj c ?

Comment: That should be useful!

Comment: Since it is your own gesture recognizer, declare it as a local property and directly access it without having to iterate through the list of all other gestures on map view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not accounting for the fact that that the array being returned by sMapView.gestureRecognizers was an optional.

Also found a bug in the initialization.

Current, working code:

init:
    var uilpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "longPressDetected:")
    uilpgr.minimumPressDuration = 1
    sMapView.addGestureRecognizer(uilpgr)

disable:

```
var recognizer = sMapView.gestureRecognizers![0] as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
recognized.enabled = false
```

enable:

```
var recognizer = sMapView.gestureRecognizers![0] as! UILongPressGestureRecognizer
recognized.enabled = true
```